# Passing Data to View Master Pages base on login user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, spark-view-engine

I've a problem with my mvc application, mvc 3 using spark view engine.
I want to bind a dropdownlist that attached to application.spark (master page) base on HttpContext.User.Identity.
the problem is..where I should place the ViewData that contain the SelectList as my DropDownList datasource ?
This dropdown list will be accessed in all page in my application.
there is an article about it : http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/passing-data-to-view-master-pages-cs, but it didn't solved my problem, since I can't got User.Identity from ApplicationController.

any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

- You could create your own base Controller and override the `OnActionExecuting` method.

  ```
  protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContextfilterContext)
  {
      var userName = User.Identity.Name;
      ViewData["MySelectList"] = new SelectList(AllUsers, "Id", "UserName", userName );
  }
  ```
- You could create an [action filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209.aspx) and override the 'OnActionExecuting' method - then apply that filter to every controller.

  ```
   public class MyCustomActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
   {
     public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
     {
       var userName =  filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData["MySelectList"] = new SelectList(AllUsers, "Id", "UserName", userName);
     }
   }

  [MyCustomActionFilter]
  public class HomeController:Controller
  {....
  }
  ```